# Trigger on a timer using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of tabs.

You hover over the tab and it loads in the tab content.

What my client would like to do is when you hover out load back in the home tab. 
Now this is causing some problems with my hover, In that you hover down the list and it always flicks back to the home tab. Which is correct, But what I'd like to do is wait for 3 or 4 seconds to load the home tab back in. Or otherwise load the next hovered tab in the sequence.

Hope this makes sense,

My current code is...

```
$('div.vertical_tabs ul.st_tabs li a').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).trigger('click');
} , function() {
            $('.home').trigger('click');
}           
});
```

Any help appreciated on this one.

Comment: You can start a timeout interval that will store it's value inside the data-attribute of the hovered object. Just an idea.

Comment: Not quite sure how I achieve this?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle test case? I'll try to implement it in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it should look like this:

```
$('div.vertical_tabs ul.st_tabs li a').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout($('.home').data('timeout'));
    $(this).trigger('click');   
}, function() {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.home').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
    $('.home').data('timeout', t);
});
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsbin.com/uyizud/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: That is perfect. I can see what you've done with it too. Wasnt too sure whether setInterval or setTimeout would have been the right approach for it.

Many Thanks

Comment: P.S, you know that instead of using `.trigger()` you can just do e.g: `$(this).click();` http://jsbin.com/uyizud/2/edit